# My iOS simulator does not display view correctly. It moves the contents to the right

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, ios8.1

I just defined a custom view and defined a drawRect() to draw a circle in the center of the view. See code below. However when I run it, the circle is shifted to the right margin. I am running Xcode 6.3.1 on MAC OS 10.10.3 Yosemite

```
@IBDesignable
class FaceView: UIView
{
override func drawRect(regionThatNeedsToBeDrawn: CGRect){

    var rect = regionThatNeedsToBeDrawn
    var faceCenter = convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: faceCenter, radius: CGFloat(50.0), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    UIColor.redColor().setFill()
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 3.0
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()          
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want the circle in the middle of FaceView? How is face view positioned in *its* superview?

Comment: What does't it mean by shifter to the right margin? BTW the code is working fine for me http://www.filedropper.com/iossimulatorscreenshotmay282015102145am

Comment: I think your problem is where you have FaceView positioned. Your code correctly centers the circle within FaceView.

Comment: Code works fine. It positions path object in centre, but try to check how you are positioning your Faceview view in its superview.